# Canvas - Is it possible fill over only a specific element on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a main circle in the center. There are circles that are outside this that are always just touching the main circle. Outside circles can overlap each other.

Outside circles can have any line width, and for outside circles that have a smaller line width than the center circle, I'm trying to "eat into" the main circle.

If there were no overlapping circles, I could just set the outside circles to fill, which will eat in at the main circle. However, outside circles can overlap and filling them may break other outside circles.

**Here's a picture to explain better:**
[image]

**Here's a snippet showing the above example:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas"),
    ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
canvas.width  = $(window).width();
canvas.height = $(window).height();

drawCircle(174, 174, 100, 20);
drawCircle(300, 300, 75, 15);
drawCircle(400, 400, 66, 5);
drawCircle(325, 423, 50, 7);

function drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius, lineWidth) {
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    //canvasContext.fillStyle = "#22313f";
    ctx.arc(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius, getRadiansFromPercentage(0), getRadiansFromPercentage(1)); // centerX, centerY, radius, startRadians, endRadians

    ctx.stroke();
}

function getRadiansFromPercentage(percentage) {
  var radians = (percentage * 360) * (Math.PI / 180); // turn percentage to degrees, then to radians

  return radians - 0.5 * Math.PI; // - 0.5 * Math.PI so "0.00" starts at the top of the circle
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
```

**The end goal is for my project to look something like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you first draw the center circle as normal, then draw all the outside circles filled using `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"` this will remove pixels from the center circle. When all the outside circles rendered then set `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"` and render the outside circles as normal.

Example code with random circles. I think this is what you are after.

```js
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 512;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const circle = {
   x : 256,
   y : 256,
   r : 150,
   w : 10,
}

const circles = [];
function randCircle(){
  const ang = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  const r = Math.random() * 100 + 50;
  const w = Math.random() * 18 + 2;
  const dist = circle.r - circle.w/2 + (r - w/2 );
  circles.push({
    x : circle.x + Math.cos(ang) * dist,
    y : circle.y + Math.sin(ang) * dist,
    r,
    w,
  })
}
function doit(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,512,512);
  circles.length = 0;
  /// some random circles
  for(let i = 0; i < 8; i ++){
    randCircle();
  }


  function renderAll(){
     ctx.lineWidth = circle.w;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0 , Math.PI * 2);
     ctx.stroke();
     ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
     ctx.beginPath();
     for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i ++){
       var c = circles[i];
       ctx.moveTo(c.x + c.r,c.y);
       ctx.arc(c.x,c.y,c.r,0,Math.PI * 2);
     }
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
     for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i ++){
       ctx.beginPath();
       var c = circles[i];
       ctx.lineWidth = c.w;
       ctx.arc(c.x,c.y,c.r,0,Math.PI * 2);
       ctx.stroke();
     }

  }

  renderAll();
}

canvas.onclick = doit;
doit();
```

```css
canvas {
 border : 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
Click canvas to randomise.<br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after, thanks!  I'm just taking your explanation at the top and am implementing it into my example, but can't seem to replicate it. In your example, you're doing .moveTo() when using destination-out... is this important? In my example, using fill() seems to completely remove the outer circles. https://jsfiddle.net/7u7f9nvb/2/

Comment: @TobyMellor the `moveTo` is to prevent the fill joining the arcs. The moveTo moves to the beginning of the arc which is at the 3oclock pos. You could also move the `beginPath()` and `fill()` to inside that for loop and then you dont need the `moveTo`

Comment: Thanks for the help!